# Azure Diagnostics: Access to the path '(GUID)-mswapd-lock' is denied?

Tags: connection-string, azure-diagnostics

***Code and configuration:***

I've enabled Diagnostics per the official tutorial at https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/. My diagnostic initializer is invoked from Global.asax (no WebRole.cs for this WCF ported to Azure WebRole) and its quite simple like:

```
public bool Initialize()
{
    DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
    config.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
    config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);
    DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);

    return true;
}
```

***Cloud and Local strings same:***

I'm using the SAME cloud based diagnostic connection string for `local` and `cloud` configurations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="MyApp.API.Azure1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="2" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2012-05.1.7">
  <Role name="MyApp.API">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      ...
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ConfigStoreConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myapi;AccountKey=MyVeryLongStringHereWhichIsActuallyAKeyForAPlaceInTheCloudWhereUnicornsDanceUnderDoubleRainbows" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="ThumbPrintStringsAreBiggerThanPinkiePrintString" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    </Certificates>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

***Error:***

When I run the above within Azure Emulator (local compute) I do not get the error (despite the cloud connection string for diagnostics). When I run the webrole on Azure (with same diagnostic sting and of course, code), I get the following error:

```
    [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '05d5e525-e1bc-4a37-8bfb-010bb2941301-mswapd-lock' is denied.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +12895415
   System.Threading.MutexTryCodeHelper.MutexTryCode(Object userData) +229
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) +0
   System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew, MutexSecurity mutexSecurity) +629
   System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew) +18
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.StartDiagnosticsMonitorProcess(DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo info) +171
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.ReconfigureMonitoringProcess(ConfigRequest req) +209
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.UpdateState(DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo startupInfo) +207
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.StartWithExplicitConfiguration(DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo startupInfo, DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration initialConfiguration) +643
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.Start(CloudStorageAccount storageAccount, DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration initialConfiguration) +47
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.Start(String diagnosticsStorageAccountConfigurationSettingName, DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration initialConfiguration) +108
   myApp.api.Diag.Diagnostics.Initialize() in c:\Work\MyApp.API\source\Diag\Diagnostics.cs:42
   Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Work\MyApp.API\source\Global.asax.cs:30
```

***Attempts: None worked***

- Disabled all Azure monitoring and logging (from portal) for this storage account in case Azure's own monitoring/logging mechanisms were locking it down
- Replaced  `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` with real cloud connection string for diagnostics even for local configuration (local compute/Azure emulator).
- Simplified diagnostic initializer to bare minimum (seen above). However, `DiagnosticMonitor.Start(...)` always fails.
- Created *another* diagnostic connection string in .cscfg file (with reference in .csdef too) so that if the original `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString` is also used by Azure infrastructure, I have another string for it. No help, same error.

I've burnt many hours trying to debug this but I *always* get this error on Azure.

***Question:***

Can someone help me get rid of this error? I can try a few ideas you may have. I'm disappointed by the MS tutorial but disappointment doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same symptoms here (but in an ASP.NET MVC application).

Basically you shouldn't be using the DiagnosticMonitor.Start() any more.

The below worked for me (Azure SDK 1.8, October 2012)

I simplified the init code from this article: 
http://convective.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/configuration-changes-to-windows-azure-diagnostics-in-azure-sdk-v1-3/

```cs
    private void ConfigureDiagnostics()
    {
        var wadConnectionString ="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString";

        var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(wadConnectionString));

        var roleInstanceDiagnosticManager =
                cloudStorageAccount.CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(
                    RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId,
                    RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name,
                    RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);

        var diagnosticMonitorConfiguration = roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.GetCurrentConfiguration();

        diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1d);

        diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1d);

        diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;
        roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.SetCurrentConfiguration(diagnosticMonitorConfiguration);
    }
```

I'm calling it from the Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs and it works fine now. Both locally and in the cloud.

You also need this in your web.config:

```xml
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

and this in your ServiceDefinition.csdef 's WebRole section:

```xml
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
</Imports>
```

These are added by the wizard by default, but still worth checking when migrating existing code to Azure.

A note to log4net users: 
Specialized appenders are not really necessary, you can use the standard log4net.Appender.TraceAppender which comes with log4net - just configure it in your web.config and init log4net as usual it in your Application_Start() or prior to the 1st use.

Answer (score 0):

Removing from trace listeners element this line fixed the problem for me.

```
<add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics" />
```

Know I'm thinking how to update already existing application configuration and not create one during the application start.